# Extjs - cant load content to panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, panel

I created Extjs.Panel and now I would like to dynamically load a content to it. So I wrote this simple code

```
Ext.get('contentPanel').load({
                    url: '@Url.Action("TempView","Home")'

                    });
```

After executing this function, panel is populated with TempView, however couple of seconds later I get an error in Extjs library

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:Unable to get value of the property
>   'events': object is null or undefined.

EDIT
I flollowed @DmitryB advice and I used debug version of library. Here is what I found out. It turned out that the problem is in function

```
getElementEventCache
```

which is defined in file ext-all-debug.js in line 11108. The function looks this way

```
getElementEventCache : function(element) {
        if (!element) {
            return {};
        }
        var elementCache = Ext.cache[this.getId(element)];
        return elementCache.events || (elementCache.events = {});
    },
```

The exception is thrown in the last line, because of the fact that elementCache is null.

[image]
Here is the stacktrace from visualstudio

[image]

Comment: run this in Chrome to see the full stack trace. Also switch to debug version of extjs to get a better understanding of the error. It may or may not be related to your load event.

Comment: @DmitryB I edited my question and added some more information

Comment: Unfortunately I have not seen this before. What is the 'element' in this function that throws exception? Also you mentioned: 'The exception is thrown in the last name'. What did you mean by that? What is the content of the load event, have you tried scripts:true option?

Comment: another thing you might want to try is take a look at this example. see if you can reproduce the error there. http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/xqLPa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar error that was resolved by adding the following line. (from [this forum thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134209-4.0.1-IE8-events-is-null-or-not-an-object))

```
if(Ext.isIE) {
    Ext.enableGarbageCollector=false;
}
```

Comment: If you're only getting this error in IE, it looks like the same error I ran into. The stack trace leads back to the garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bellow code and work cool. This may help you.

Try this

```
var content_div = Ext.get(div_id);
    content_div.load({
    url:your_url,params:{id:'abc'},scripts:true,text: 'Loading...'});
    content_div.show();
```

Comment: contentPanel is any html tag id or Extjs component Id. If it is Extjs component then access with Ext.getCmp('contentPanel');